# Is it possible to control the speed of the fan on my central A/C unit?

Tags: air-conditioning, thermostat

I have one of those medium sized AC-units (don't know the model name at the moment) and a very basic Honeywell thermostat that the installers put in when the house was built.

However, there doesn't seem to be much options.  I can only turn the fan on or off, AC on or off, set the schedule, and the desired temp.

Is there a way to control the fan speed (It's quite loud and I'm planning on renting the basement out... with the AC unit right next to the basement window) like those portable AC units? Is this dependent on the thermostat or the AC unit itself?

Comment: Do you want to control the speed of the outside condensing unit fan, or the inside blower fan?  What type of A/C system do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Condensing Unit Fan

If you're talking about controlling the speed of the fan in the outside condensing unit, the answer is no.

[image: Condensing Unit]

The job of this fan, is to remove heat from the refrigerant flowing through the system. Reducing the speed of the fan would reduce the cooling effectiveness of the system, and could lead to damage to, or premature failure of the system.

## Blower Fan

If you're talking about reducing the speed of the blower fan (the fan that circulates air throughout the house), the answer is no again.

The job of this fan is to add heat to the refrigerant flowing through the system. Reducing the speed of the fan would reduce the cooling effectiveness of the system, and could lead to damage to, or premature failure of the system.

Comment: +1 Nice Answer - Although probably off tune music to the ears of the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  So there's nothing I can do... but how come those portable A/Cs have fan speed settings?

Comment: @jack I'm not sure what portable A/C's you're talking about, could you supply a link?

Comment: He's talking about the fan speed setting on a window mounted portable A/C unit. To the OP: An A/C has two heat exchangers, with fans blowing air across them. In a window A/C unit, it is the evaporator fan that has adjustable speed. This is equivalent to the fan _inside_ your house with a split (aka "central") A/C system. There are in fact air handlers with variable speed fans. (Search "variable speed air handler") But they have to be made that way. Now, back to the key point: You said the A/C unit is right next to the window. If that is the outside condenser unit, it will be constant speed.

Comment: I will add that I've heard of variable speed A/C compressors, but it's the same as the air handler: If it was built as a constant speed unit, you can't change that. In theory you could pull it apart and find a replacement variable-speed motor that fits, add controls for it, but I think that is beyond the scope of what you're asking

Comment: @TimB The blower fan in a furnace is typically multi-speed, however, it's most often set up at a specific speed.  The other speeds come in when you start getting in to multiple stages, and other more advanced setups. As for the condensing unit. If a variable/multi- speed fan *was* used, it would have to be controlled by a complex system of temperature sensors.  Even then, unless the unit was far oversized, it would likely run at full speed anyway.

Comment: @Tester101 Technically, most blowers are multi-speed (3–5 discrete speeds; variable speed commonly refers to a continuous range of speeds). Heating and cooling typically use different speeds, which are configurable by changing the wiring on the blower motor. The only reason you'd want to change the speed is if you currently aren't getting enough airflow across your evaporator coil (350–450 cfm/ton).

Comment: A/C air-handlers almost always call for the highest speed. Cold air is denser and harder to push. The second answer is not a "no"; it's *don't*.

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous instructional videos on how to change the air speed CFM on an airhandler, so YES.  Rather than a switch, it is achieved by the wiring.  There will be a chart and a wiring diagram on the unit that will direct you.  One speed of air does not match all configurations.  A specific CFM on a 3 ton unit with a single trunk line feeding a shotgun house might not be the same as a 4 ton unit with a different duct set up, yet the air handler itself might be the same.

Comment: "Control" ? not so much. *Set* by changing which wire the A/C uses to power the bower? YES (not that you'd really want it any lower).